# Postgres 8.3 correct deletion of files in pgsql_tmp

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-8.3

We are talking about the PostgreSQL 8.3 RDBMS here. So, no `pg_terminate_backend()` is possible with this version.

Sometimes we have to kill running processes at Operating System level (`kill -9 PID`) to solve issues related to `max_connections` value reached. In such cases, we targeted long running SELECT queries to kill.

As a result, we found out that our filesystem grows at 98% and fills up quickly, showing 1500+ files in the `pgsql_tmp` directory.

Some orphan files are the expected result of this kind of maneuver, since Temp files should be deleted during `proc_exit` processing and aggressively terminating running processes are not the best option.

So, to get rid of this "trash", what is our best option:

1. Conduct a postmaster restart and expect the RDBMS will run around and clean out all the temp directories by itself; or
2. stop the postmaster, manually delete the files in `$PGDATA/pgsql_tmp/` and then, start postmaster again; or
3. without stopping the server, manually delete the files in `$PGDATA/pgsql_tmp/` which are older than the current day.

Please justify your answer(s).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than seeking better ways to suture up your foot, you should just stop shooting yourself in the foot.

All that pg_terminate_backend does is check for permission, then deliver a SIGTERM. You can do this directly by using `kill -15 PID` rather than `kill -9 PID`.  This will give that one process a chance to clean up after itself before exiting.  More importantly, it will not needlessly kill every other process and trigger a crash recovery.

If that process is so wedged that it won't respond to `kill -15`, then pg_terminate_backend wouldn't help anyway.  And in that case, it is probably a bug, and using software that is not 5 years past its EOL would likely help there.  If it is wedged like that, then rather than killing it with `-9`, you could probably just restart the server with `pg_ctl restart -mi`.  It would accomplish the same thing, but would clean up the files for itself.

If you are really only interested in better ways to suture up your foot, then your option 1 should work fine.  Option 2 seems pointless, since 1 works.

Your option 3 should also work as long as one day is long enough to avoid any still-running processes.  If you remove a file that some process still needed, the worst that happens is that that one process throws an error (which you must already be used to, as a user of `kill -9`). I would say it is not a "best practice", but since you are running long out-of-support software and routinely using `kill -9`, the best practice ship has already sailed.